# What is the difference between updating the value of a Linkedlist within a method in these two ways?

Tags: java

I am writing a queue structure using Linkedlist. And I am writing the method to add elements to the queue. Since the question specifies that the method should have signiture of void enqueueCharacter(char ch), therefore I wrote another method with signiture void enqCharacter(queueNode q, char ch) and called this method inside enqueueCharacter.

At first it failed and I have no clue why. I made a small change just to try and it worked. But in fact I think they should either both work or both fail because (I think) they have the exact the same concept.

Here is the definition of the queueNode:

```
class queueNode
{
    char head;
    queueNode tail;
    queueNode(char c)
    {
        head = c;
        tail = null;
    }
}
```

and the declaration of queue:

```
queueNode queue = null;
```

This is what I originally wrote to update the queue:

```
public void enqCharacter(queueNode q, char ch)
{
    if( q == null ) q = new queueNode( ch );
    else enqCharacter( q.tail, ch );
}

public void enqueueCharacter(char ch)
{
    enqCharacter( queue, ch );
}
```

The concept is to call enqCharacter( queue, ch ) as soon as I call enqueueCharacter(char ch) and do nothing else. And in enqCharacter(queueNode q, char ch), I check if q is null, if yes, then add the first element to q, otherwise do the same to q.tail. But I checked and it turns out that I never really changed the value of queue, but it should since I passed queue to the method (I tried passing this.queue as well but still not working).

Then I changed it slightly:

```
public void enqCharacter(queueNode q, char ch)
{
    if( q.tail == null ) q.tail = new queueNode( ch );
    else enqCharacter( q.tail, ch );
}

public void enqueueCharacter(char ch)
{
    if( queue == null ) queue = new queueNode( ch );
    else enqCharacter( queue, ch );
}
```

I made these changes only because I have no other idea, not because I think this is better, but it worked. And I still don't know why.

Can anyone explain why I should update the tail instead of the queue itself? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Java is 'pass-by-value'.

when you send q.tail as parameter to the method, you are sending the value, as this is a reference type the value would be the object location to which this reference(q.tail) refers to.

So When q.tail is null, you are sending the null value(i.e. null reference) as parameter to the method enqCharacter and then assigning the new queueNode object to this null reference.

But in second case you are not sending null reference as parameter to enqCharacter in any case and hence you can retain the chain in second case, because you have reference to that chain. In first case you just lost the referenece once you send null as parameter and then assign a brand new queueNode object.

Comment: Oh I see. But if I want to send the reference of queue no matter if it is null, what should I do? use &queue?

Comment: In your situation consider a chain: A-B-C: Suppose where A is friend of B and B is of C and C is friend of nobody, now you want to attach somebody to C as friend hence you send this nobody(null reference) as parameter to method and parameter being nobody(null), method assigned a new brand person say D to this nobody, but there is no way method can attach that D to C because method don't have C's reference to attach D to it. Hence D remains floating somewhere in universe without having attachment to anybody.
Also you cant use &queue in java.